# Nginx regular expression server_name

Tags: regex, nginx, server-name, nginx-location

How can you use regular expression to do this:

```
preprod.*.company.com > root to /home/preprod_folder
*.company.com > root to /home/prod_folder
```

I know that to match *.company.com I will create:

```
server_name *.company.com
```

But what about for a regular expression that match before ***.company.com**, this rule **preprod.allsubdomains.company.com**

`preprod.*.company.com` is not working, and that's normal.

Could you help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "redirect", but it looks like your intent is to set the `root` directory instead. Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
    server_name ~^preprod\.(?<subdomain>\w+).company.com;
    root /home/prepod_folder;
```

Comment: Yes this is working, but If I add the other rule *.company.com (so both rules), *.company.com match before your rule..

Comment: I added this rule also for *.company.com (    server_name ~^(?!preprod)\.(?<subdomain>\w+).mycompany.com; )) and this is working, thanks!